# How do you create a custom template to display a category with an image and related posts below?

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, post-thumbnails, page-template

I am trying to create a custom template that can give the following effect...

- Category Name A (with image)

  - post with category name A
  - post 2 with category name A
  - post 3 with category name A
- Category Name B (with image)

  - post with category name B
  - post 2 with category name B
  - post 3 with category name B

Should I do this with custom post types? If so, do I have create two, or can I manage this with one custom post type?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand exactly the problem, but If I do - there is absolutely no need for a custom post type.

all you have to do is use [multiple loops](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Multiple_Loops_in_Action) and basically divide the query into sub-loops for each category .

```
<div id="cat-1">
     <?php query_posts('cat=1&posts_per_page=5');// put relevant category and number of posts
         if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
         // Do whatever ...
     endwhile; endif; reset_query();?>

</div>

<div id="cat-2">
     <?php query_posts('cat=2&posts_per_page=1');// put relevant category and number of posts
          if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
          // Do whatever ..
     endwhile; endif; reset_query(); ?>
</div>

<div id="cat-3">
     <?php query_posts('cat=3&posts_per_page=-1');// put relevant category and number of posts
          if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
          // Do whatever ..
     endwhile; endif; reset_query();?>
</div>..etc.. etc..
```

Note that you can do the same using Loops with `query_posts()` , Loops with `WP_Query()` or Loops with `get_posts()`.

regarding the image - I am not sure what Image you want - but if you refer to a category image (special image assigned to categories) you will need to use some plugin [like these](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=category%20image) ..